# Galaxy S5 (SM-G900H) unknown baseband

Tags: rooting, imei, baseband

Background Story :
The S5 belongs to my friend. One day, he was no longer able to make or receive calls and he came to me for help.

[image: Details]

As you can see above, the baseband version of the phone is "unknown". When I checked the IMEI, it says null.

So I searched forums for the solution. It turned out that the EFS partition was either corrupted or deleted ( source : 
http://techbeasts.com/how-to-restore-and-back-up-efs-data-on-samsung-galaxy-devices/ ).

According to the site, I need to get my phone rooted to use the EFS recovery software.

However, I encountered another problem there. I used the latest version of CF-AutoRoot to get the phone rooted. Despite Odin showing success, the phone enters a boot loop. I manage to get out of it ( by wiping cache, etc ) only to find the phone not rooted.

Long story short : is there a way to recover EFS without rooting? Or is there a way to root the S5

Note : Other people on the internet managed to root their S5 ( same model ) but their build was different (XXU). Is there a possibility that the build of this S5 (XXS) is causing the error.